# ColdFusion 9 Verity Update

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, verity, cfindex

I have a usable Verity collection, initially populated thusly:

```
<cfindex action="refresh" type="custom" body="PageTitle,PageText" 
   collection="ABC" custom1="PageID" custom2="MenuName" 
   key="PageID" query="GetPages" title="PageTitle">
```

GetPages query looks something like this:

```
PageID  PageTitle       PageText   MenuName
-------------------------------------------
100     About XYZ Corp  <content>  About Us
200     XYZs Products   <content>  Products
300     XYZs Services   <content>  Services
```

Along comes a new page that needs to be added to the collection:

```
PageID  PageTitle       PageText   MenuName
-------------------------------------------
400     XYZ News        <content>  News
```

How do I add this to ABC without having to rebuild the entire collection? I've tried variations of `<cfindex action="update" ...>` without success, usually locking the collection and requiring a CF restart. I can't seem to find good working examples online, and what I do find seems vague. I can successfully purge and rebuild collection using `<cfindex action="refresh"...>`, but that's so process intensive to do regularly.

Environment: CF9 / IIS / WinServ 2008 R2; collection is ~300 documents at 1,500KB.

Limitations: app is in EOL phase so collection won't be migrated to SOLR; I have little experience using CF's search tools (engineers have done this for me up to now).

Comment: it's been ages since I've used Verity in CF, but a question. When you're trying `<cfindex action="update" ... />` are you trying to update every record or just the new ones? I can't see why the collection would be locked if you're just trying to add a few files.

Comment: Just trying to add the new ones.

Comment: how many are you trying to add? Have you tried limiting the result set of your query to maybe add one at a time and see what happens?

Comment: that is very strange. The only thing I can suggest is that you create a new collection and try rebuilding the index there. Maybe the original collection is corrupted somehow. For what it's worth (and I know that this isn't an option for you at the moment), making the switch to Solr is well worth it.